# React native opentok publisher not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to mimic a calling system in an app using `react-native-opentok`. I successfully initiated the voice call method simply by using the `<Publish />` and `<Subscribe />` but when I added the `video={true}` to the both in order to start a video call session, the subscribe in my simulator is showing me the camera from my real device although I cannot see myself as a `<Publisher />`; from my real device it keeps showing me a blank canvas.

Here is my video call component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import Container from '@components/container';
import Api from '@utils/api';
import { Icon } from 'native-base';
import NewCall from '@components/new-call';
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';
import OpenTok, { Publisher, Subscriber } from 'react-native-opentok';

class VideoCall extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loading: true, call_answered: false, status: '' };
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {

    await this.setup_component();

    await this.connect_to_session();

  }

  setup_component = async () => {

    await this.setState({ appointment: this.props.navigation.getParam('appointment'), status: this.props.navigation.getParam('status'), loading: false })

    OpenTok.on(OpenTok.events.ON_SIGNAL_RECEIVED, e => {

      if (e.type == 'answered') this.setState({ status: e.type })

      if (e.type == 'hangup') this.hangup('hunged up')

    })

  }

  connect_to_session = async () => {

    try {

      if (this.state.status == 'calling') OpenTok.sendSignal(this.state.appointment.call_session, 'video_call')

      if (this.state.status == 'getting a call') this.ring()

    } catch (e) {

      console.warn(e);

    }

  }

  respond = async (e) => {

    if (await e == 'answered') {

      await this.setState({ status: e })

      OpenTok.sendSignal(this.state.appointment.call_session, 'answered')

    }

  }

  ring = () => {

    let ringtone = new Sound('default_ringtone.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, error => {
      if (error) {
        console.warn(error);
        return;
      }
    })

    ringtone.play((success) => {
      if (success) console.warn('successfully playing')
      else {
        console.warn('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
        whoosh.reset();
      }
    })

    ringtone.release()

  }

  hangup = (e) => {

    if (e == 'hunged up') {

      OpenTok.disconnect(this.state.appointment.call_session);

      this.props.navigation.goBack(null)

    } else {

      OpenTok.sendSignal(this.state.appointment.call_session, 'hangup')

      OpenTok.disconnect(this.state.appointment.call_session);

      this.props.navigation.goBack(null)

    }

  }

  render() {

    if (!this.state.appointment) return false;

    return (

      <Container loading={ this.state.loading }>

        <Image source={ require('@images/audio-call.png')} style={{ position: 'absolute', width: '100%', height: '100%' }} />

        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, position: 'relative' }}>

          {
            (this.state.status == 'answered')

            ? <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}>

                <Publisher
                  style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, zIndex: 90 }}
                  sessionId={this.state.appointment.call_session}
                  video={ true }
                  onSubscribeStart={() => {
                    console.log('subscription started');
                  }}
                  videoScale="fill"
                  cameraDirection="front"
                  onSubscribeStop={() => {
                    console.log('subscription stopped');
                  }}
                />

                <Subscriber
                  sessionId={this.state.appointment.call_session}
                  onPublishStart={() => {
                    console.log('publish started');
                  }}
                  onPublishStop={() => {
                    console.log('publish stoped');
                  }}
                  style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 40, right: 10, width: 100, height: 200, zIndex: 100 }}
                  video={ true }
                  ref={ref => {
                    this.publisherRef = ref;
                  }}
                />

                {/* <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 40, right: 10, width: 100, height: 200, zIndex: 100, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> */}

              </View>

            : null

          }

          <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-start', paddingTop: 50 }}>

            { (this.state.status == 'calling' || this.state.status == 'getting a call')

              ? <View style={{ width: 200, height: 200, borderRadius: 100, backgroundColor: '#a4a4a4' }}>

                  <Image source={ require('@images/male-avatar.png') } style={{ width: 200, height: 200, resizeMode: 'cover' }} />

                </View>

              : null

            }

          </View>

          {
            (this.state.status == 'getting a call')

            ? <NewCall respond={ this.respond } />

            : (this.state.status == 'calling')

            ? <View style={{ flex: 0, paddingVertical: 40, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

                <Text style={{ color: '#fff', fontFamily: 'DINNextLTArabic-Regular', fontSize: 22, lineHeight: 24 }}>Calling ...</Text>

              </View>

            : (this.state.status == 'answered')

            ? <View style={{ flex: 0, paddingVertical: 30, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

                <Text style={{ color: '#fff', fontSize: 22, lineHeight: 24, fontFamily: 'DINNextLTArabic-Regular', marginVertical: 10 }}>02:25</Text>

                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

                  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: 80, height: 80, borderRadius: 100, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#A7A8C4' }}>
                      <Icon name="megaphone" type="Foundation" style={{ fontSize: 40, color: '#26296A', marginTop: 5 }} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>

                  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 100, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#E16897' }}>
                      <Icon name="phone" type="Feather" style={{ fontSize: 40, color: '#fff', lineHeight: 42, transform: [{ rotate: '135deg' }] }} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>

                  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: 80, height: 80, borderRadius: 100, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#A7A8C4' }}>
                      <Icon name="microphone-off" type="MaterialCommunityIcons" style={{ fontSize: 40, color: '#26296A', lineHeight: 42 }} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>

                </View>

              </View>

            : null

          }

        </SafeAreaView>

      </Container>

    );

  }

}

export default VideoCall;
```

What could possibly be wrong here?